# Trig problem, choppy movement of a triangle around a circle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, trigonometry

The code below is supposed to rotate a triangle around an "invisible" circle. It is working just as I intended, however, the triangle seems to stutter around this "circle" sometimes. The CPU and memory load of this thing seem to be OK, so I wonder if it is an issue with the rounding and drawing... Help appreciated.
P.S I am using SetInterval to establish a framerate. A framerate of >30 is required for what I am trying to do.
Thanks.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("game_area");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var angle = 0;

var SinA = Math.sin(Math.PI);
var CosA = Math.cos(Math.PI);

var SinB = Math.sin(Math.PI-0.087);
var CosB = Math.cos(Math.PI-0.087);

var SinC = Math.sin(Math.PI+0.087);
var CosC = Math.cos(Math.PI+0.087);

canvas.width = 700;
canvas.height = 700;

var half = (canvas.width/2);

function on_enter_frame(){

    SinA = Math.sin(Math.PI+angle);
    CosA = Math.cos(Math.PI+angle);

    SinB = Math.sin(Math.PI-0.087+angle);
    CosB = Math.cos(Math.PI-0.087+angle);

    SinC = Math.sin(Math.PI+0.087+angle);
    CosC = Math.cos(Math.PI+0.087+angle);

    angle+=0.05;

    if (angle>(Math.PI*2)){
        angle=0;
    }

    context.clearRect(0,0,500,500);

    context.fillStyle = "#FFF";

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(half+(SinA*50), half+(CosA*50));
    context.lineTo(half+(SinB*45), half+(CosB*45));
    context.lineTo(half+(SinC*45), half+(CosC*45));
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();
}

setInterval(on_enter_frame,30);
```

Comment: Have you considered using layered canvases? Perhaps too much is being redrawn at a time?

Comment: You shouldn't use `setInterval` for animations. You should use `requestAnimationFrame` instead. It is supported in most of the modern browsers. [Microsoft Demo](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/RequestAnimationFrame/Default.html), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.mozRequestAnimationFrame)

Comment: tjameson: Only one thing is being drawn, how would a layered canvas help?
@Derek: I will look into requestAnimationFrame, do you believe that this could be attributable to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

See http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/ for an explanation of requestAnimationFrame and why to use it.

The reality is that neither `requestAnimationFrame` nor `setInterval` will provide rock solid timing, although your chances should be better with `requestAnimationFrame`. The stutter you're getting might be due to other processes on your computer, or even garbage collection in your current JS process.

Since your loop timing will never be reliable, it's better to base your animation (in this case the position of your orbiting triangle) on actual time (or time elapsed since the previous frame).

I can't see the stutter you're getting, so I don't know whether this will be an improvement, but you can look at a live example of how `requestAnimationFrame` and elapsed time are used here: http://jsfiddle.net/xpZxy/

Comment: Thanks for the healp, but unfortunately, I still see the jitter, even in your FiddleJS example. I am using Firefox 5.0, but I guess that this must be something with my computer then...

Comment: @jonh is the stutter/jitter in the position or the orientation or the shape?

Comment: Id say mainly position, the triangle seem to stop briefly and then "skips a step" to make up for its idleness. I've tried rounding terms, changing speeds and frame rates, but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: @jonh, hard to say whether it's FF or your computer.  There are more recent versions of FF, and it's also easy to install other browsers like Chrome.  Finally, there is an orbiting ball demo on the Paul Irish page .. what does it look like on your setup?

Comment: It had the same choppy feel as the triangle. Guess we just pinpointed the problem... Downloading chrome as we speak :)